# How do I create a node with Label via REST API in Neo4j 2.0

Tags: java, neo4j

I have been searching for info on this but to no avail... yet. How do I create a new node complete with a label in one swoop using the Rest API? Right now, the only way I can seem to accomplish this is using the code below.

```
        try (Transaction tx = gd.beginTx()) {
            Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
            //do stuff with props...
            RestNode node = gd.createNode(props);
            node.addLabel(Labels.Person);
            log.debug("Node: username - " + node.getProperty("username")
                    + " added");
            tx.success();
        }
```

When I want to insert, say 100 nodes using this approach, I feel I should be able to do without the extra call to add the label. Anyway I can optimise this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying RestAPI(Facade) has a `addLabels()` method that you can use, but I wouldn't recommend it.

The transaction won't work if you want to read your writes.

If you want to insert 100 nodes with labels and properties, use Cypher with Parameters.

This should work.

```
restQueryEngine.query("foreach (p in {names} | create (n:Person {name:name}))",         
                      map("names",asList("John","Jane",...)));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael... was just listening to your webinar on upcoming features on Neo4j 2.0. Nice. Question though... Say I have a list of props I want to assign to a node which are put together in a java Map collection, how would I go about it using the snippet above?

Comment: Additionally Michael, I am assuming the map and asList are static imports? Which packages will I find these?

Comment: I think i've wrapped my head around it. Poking around the [documentation](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-cypher-parameters-java.html) and comparing with your snippet did the trick. Thanks.